# Причастный оборот или просто причастие?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастия, причастный-оборот

Нужны ли запятые: "Из двенадцати(,) осмелившихся покуситься на драконов(,) трое погибли"?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, причастным оборотом можно было считать конструкцию, в которой присутствовало бы определяемое слово "человек". Закономерно звучал бы вопрос: "Каких двенадцати человек?" Но в данной предложении от слова "двенадцати" следует вопрос: "Двенадцати кого?". Следовательно, слово "осмелившихся" является в этом предложении прилагательным с элементом субстантивации. Замечу, что такая трактовка применима к предложенному порядку расположения членов предложения (инверсии)

Answer (score 2):

***Из двенадцати осмелившихся покуситься на драконов трое погибли.***

Запятые не ставятся, так как здесь цельное количественно-именное сочетание с распространённой именной частью "осмелившихся покуситься на драконов". Ср.: *Из двенадцати человек трое погибли*.

Answer (score 0):

Причастный оборот конечно. ...Трудно объяснить это.
В сочетании «осмелившихся покусится на дракона» слова образуют словосочетания, связанны с друг другом грамматически, последовательно относятся к друг другу.
Осмелившихся что сделать? — покусится. Когда есть подобная связь между словами, то это не может не быть оборотом.